# When load page with Ajax, the go back button doesn't works

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'am trying to create a website where all pages are called with Ajax. When I click on any link on the page, the url and page content changes without refreshing all page (similar Facebook). So far everything is fine.

The problem is : When I click the **go back** or **go forward**  button, the url changes but the page content does not change.

Example code :

```
function loadDoc($link) {  // example for $link : /example.php
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                var doc = parser.parseFromString(xhttp.responseText, "text/html");
                var elem = doc.getElementById("content");
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", $link, true);
        xhttp.send();
        window.history.pushState('', 'Settings', $link);  // dynamic url changing 
    }
```

(Fully separate structure or additional ideas are welcomed too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used `pushState` to add an entry to the browser history, but you haven't added an event handler to determine what happens when the browser navigates back. The browser **won't** automatically memorise the state of the DOM for you.

Here is a simple example:

```
<div id="content">1</div>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>

<script>
    const div = document.querySelector('div');

    addEventListener('click', event => {
        if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'button') return;
        const last = div.textContent;
        const next = event.target.textContent;
        div.textContent = next;
        history.pushState({ value: next }, `Page ${next}`, `/page/${next}`);
    });

    addEventListener('popstate', event => {
        let state = event.state;
        if (state === null) {
            // special case: This is the state before pushState was called
            // We know what that should be:
            state = { value: 1 };
        }
        div.textContent = state.value;
        console.log('location: ' + document.location + ', state: ' + JSON.stringify(event.state));
    });
</script>
```